# Styling arrows inside Turing machine

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I need to draw Turing Machine in LaTeX.

I used following packages:

```
\usepackage{tikz, wasysym}
```

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial] (0) {$q_0$};
   \node[state] (1) [right=of 0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (2) [right=of 1] {$q_2$};
   \path[->]
    (0) edge                    node {$B\:B\:R$} (1)
    (1) edge (0)
     (1) edge [loop above]       node {$0\:0\:R$} (1)
    (1) edge [loop below]       node {$1\:1\:R$} (1)
    (1) edge                    node {$E\:E\:L$} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:

[image]

However, I would like to have different style of arrows, like here:

[image]

Could you please help me to skew these arrows a bit?

Comment: Pgfmanual at ctan.org. Look for arrows.meta .

Comment: @MS-SPO could you post simple answer? I found this `arc [start angle=180, end angle=30, radius=10pt];` but that ruins my turing machine, or I used it wrongly

Comment: I tried `(0) edge [angle=180, end angle=30, radius=10pt] (1)` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you want. Sounds like two things: a) change arrow tips, b) introducing a bend (which doesn‘t have to be an arc or circle, does it?) ? // Please >>> clarify <<< and be patient: the pros will answer soon.

Comment: bend worked... thank you very much. I used `(0) edge [bend right=15] (1)
    (1) edge [bend right=15] (0)`

Comment: @codproe Feel free to also post an answer.